# Is there anything like JSFiddle for Haxe?

Tags: haxe

I'm looking for a way to test Haxe code online. Is there anything like jsfiddle for Haxe (e.g., an online code testing tool for the Haxe programming language)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a website for that: http://try.haxe.org/ It allows Haxe programs to be run online, and tested in the browser.